# grid detection in opencv python

Tags: python, opencv, contour, hough-transform

I have an image that has items inside a grid. One stage of the problem is to detect and build a mask of the *full* grid, which can be slightly rotated clock or anticlockwise. My current CV pipeline extracts (probabilistic) Hough lines from an image and then uses its contours to filter for a set of rectangles (call the actual and the detected sets R' and R respectively). However due to occlusions and lighting conditions the hough lines (and consequently all downstream contours and lines segments) are incomplete (R << R'). Schematically the problem i must solve is to infer the missing grid components (R'- R) given the detected grid cells.

[image: Noisy Square detection]

One strategy I am considering is the following. Foreach detected rectangle contour *r* in *R* do:

1- using *fitLine()* find vertical and horizontal lines that pass through the center of *r* (see code and image below)

```py
rect = cv2.minAreaRect(r)

box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)

box = np.int0(box)

cx  = np.int0(rect[0][0])

cy  = np.int0(rect[0][1])

w   = np.int0(rect[1][0])

h   = np.int0(rect[1][1])

cv2.drawContours(img,[box],0,255,1)

[vx,vy,x,y] = cv2.fitLine(box, cv2.DIST_L2,0,0.01,0.01)

lefty  = int((-x*vy/vx) + y)

righty = int(((cols-x)*vy/vx)+y)

start   = (cols-1,righty)

end     = (0,lefty)

cv2.line(img,start,end,255,1)

# HORIZONTAL

nx,ny = 1,-vx/vy

mag = np.sqrt((1+ny**2))

vx,vy = nx/mag,ny/mag

# Now find two extreme points on the line to draw line

lefty  = int((-x*vy/vx) + y)

righty = int(((cols-x)*vy/vx)+y)

start   = (cols-1,righty)

end     = (0,lefty)

cv2.putText(img,'start',(start[0]-60,start[1]),font,0.5,255,1) 

cv2.putText(img,'end',end,font,0.5,255,1)    

cv2.line(img,start,end,255,1)
```

[image: vertical and horizontal lines that pass through a single contour]

2- create a mask of same size and rotation as the source rectangle and move along the line define in (1), drawing the same shape rectangle as the source if there is no previously detected contour in the same area

ie.
[image]

My questions are:

1. is there a more efficient and better way to solve this problem?
2. What is best way to move the mask along the line that is at an angle
   (given by cv2.minAreaRect)?

thank you

Comment: A decent sample image would be helpful.